# Postgres Order by multi columns with a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to order a Postgres query depending on conditions in the table

```
    id   sensor_id            alarmTime            clearedTime
415068        3734  2016-04-20 12:25:32    2016-04-27 21:05:44  
415070        3734  2016-04-21 12:25:32                   null
415071        3734  2016-03-22 12:25:32    2016-04-29 21:15:44          
415072        3734  2016-04-23 12:25:32                   null          
415073        3734  2016-04-20 12:25:32    2016-04-22 22:05:45          
415074        3734  2016-02-26 12:25:32    2016-04-27 23:15:24
```

From the above table I want to initially order by nulls first and alarm time with the remaining rows ordered by cleared time only. to get some thing like this

```
    id   sensor_id            alarmTime            clearedTime
415070        3734  2016-04-21 12:25:32                   null
415072        3734  2016-04-23 12:25:32                   null  
415068        3734  2016-04-20 12:25:32    2016-04-27 21:05:44  
415073        3734  2016-04-20 12:25:32    2016-04-22 22:05:45          
415071        3734  2016-03-22 12:25:32    2016-04-29 21:15:44          
415074        3734  2016-02-26 12:25:32    2016-04-27 23:15:24
```

I have tried something like this

```
select * from table
ORDER BY
case alarm.clearedTime is NOT NULL
when TRUE THEN alarmTime
else clearedTime
end  DESC NULLS FIRST;
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Your order condition isnt clear, please explain with more details

Comment: Your sample look wrong  `415072` shoul be first than `415070`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(clearedTime, alarmTime)
```

OR something like this.

```
ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN clearedTime IS NULL THEN NULL
                                      ELSE 1 
         END NULLS FIRST,
         alarm.alarmTime DESC,
         alarm.clearedTime DESC -- optional to solve tie between 415068 and 415073
```

Comment: well at first wasnt sure what was the logic. Glad that solve it. Remember the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
order by alarm.clearedTime nulls first, alarm.alarmTime
```